# Spring boot Rest thymeleaf javascript is not returning HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, spring-boot, thymeleaf

HI I am trying the example given in spring.io [getting started guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-jquery/).

it doesn't show any error but I am not getting HTML view
when I open the link http://localhost:8070/testJson in my browser all it shows is a JSON output like this

```
{"id":1,"content":"Hello World !"}
```

But I want it to show a proper HTML view, and I can not use @Controller here, I want to show HTML using Jquery javascript,  How can I do that?

here is my controller method

```
@RestController
public class MyRestController {

    private final Long counter = 1l;

    @GetMapping("/testJson")
    public TestJsonDto getTestJson(){
         TestJsonDto testJsonDto=new TestJsonDto(counter,
            "Hello World !");

    return testJsonDto;
    }
}
```

This is my Data class

```
public class TestJsonDto {

private Long id;
private String content;
public TestJsonDto(Long id, String content) {

    this.id = id;
    this.content = content;
}
public TestJsonDto() {

}
 /* 
    GETTERS AND SETTERS WILL GO HERE
*/
```

And Below is my application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class MyjarApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyjarApplication .class, args);


    }


}
```

My Html file is

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
    <title>Hello jQuery</title>
    <script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"> 
 </script>
    <script src="/my.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <p class="greeting-id">The ID is </p>
        <p class="greeting-content">The content is </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and finally, this is my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8070/testJson"
}).then(function(testJsonDto) {
   $('.greeting-id').append(testJsonDto.id);
   $('.greeting-content').append(testJsonDto.content);
});
});
```

my application.properties is here

```
server.port=8070
```

Location of my.js is under src/main/resources/static/my.js

Comment: What do you see when you access http://localhost:8070?

Comment: localhost:8070 is a different controller, there I am using @Controller annotation and presenting a model and view with a Button linked to show my /testJson, that page is shown properly

Comment: I am also using **PdfViewResolver and CsvViewResolver** in this project, could it be the problem? but my all other HTML pages are shown properly through **@Controller** and **@GetMapping** which is returning a **String** view Name

Comment: Not sure if i understand the expected behavior you are looking for. It seems you want your HTML to be render when accessing "http://localhost:8070/testJson" but that same location is already used to return a json object. You should have one path for HTML other for your endpoint

Comment: Thanks for the comment, actually this is the first time I am trying this, can you share any link or something to get started with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a front end that can interact with your API you can structure your app like this:

This code setup your application, including static resources, for instance your `resource/static/index.html` will be render for root path `localhost:8090` unless you wire this path in any controller(make sure root is not implicitly/explicitly user in any other @Controller or annotation).

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class MyjarApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(MyjarApplication .class, args);
    }
}
```

So, a simple way to render the HMTL you want is by putting that HTML at `resource/static/index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
    <title>Hello jQuery</title>
    <script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"> 
 </script>
    <script src="/my.js"></script>    
</head>    
<body>
    <div>
        <p class="greeting-id">The ID is </p>
        <p class="greeting-content">The content is </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and js should be placed at `resource/static/my.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8070/testJson"
}).then(function(testJsonDto) {
   $('.greeting-id').append(testJsonDto.id);
   $('.greeting-content').append(testJsonDto.content);
});
});
```

In your rest controller, path `/testJson` will be attended by `getTestJson()`:

```
@RestController
public class MyRestController {

    private final Long counter = 1l;

    @GetMapping("/testJson")
    public TestJsonDto getTestJson(){
         TestJsonDto testJsonDto=new TestJsonDto(counter,
            "Hello World !");

    return testJsonDto;
    }
}
```

So you access localhost:8090 to get the front-end, and thru javascript you access localhost:8090/testJson to get your API.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer, will make the changes tomorrow, unfortunately, my upvote to your answer is not  shown here because of my low reputation

Comment: No problem, let me know if you encounter any problem. Key thing when starting working rest and regular controllers is to understand which path is served by which code according to configuration. That changes as you add functionality.

Comment: But I don't want it to be rendered at root, my RootController is annotated with @Controller and is already returning a Model And View HTML page. and all my HTML files are at resources/template/*.html,   whereas my javascript file is in resources/static/my.js. and I want /testJson to be returned at /testJson and not at at root.  P.S. I am using thymeleaf here

Comment: Thank you again, Cristian Colorado.  You are a great Help :-)